# Using Mockito.when method for method that calls other method in return

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test my class but it seems that my Mockito.when() doesn't work, and I getting a "example" instead "another example".
Any ideas?

```
public class ExampleClass {
    public String create(String example){
         return doSth();
    }

    public String doSth(){
         return "example";
    }
}
```

```
public class ExampleClassTest {
    @Mock
    ExampleClass exampleClassMock;

    public void createTest(){
        when(exampleClassMock.doSth()).thenReturn("another example");

        assertEquals(exampleClassMock.create("x"), "another example");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't forget to place `@Test` annotation onto your test methods and `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` onto the test class.

Second, if you need to test the method of some class, and inside of it the other method of the same class is called which you want to mock, then you need to use @Spy:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleClassTest {

    @Spy
    ExampleClass exampleClassMock;

    @Test
    public void createTest() {
        when(exampleClassMock.doSth()).thenReturn("another example");

        assertEquals(exampleClassMock.create("x"), "another example");
    }
}
```

See [docs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) for spying.